# How can I apply filter on mail items based on received time?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the following For Each loop to import new Outlook mail into Excel. I am attempting to speed up the routine and am having trouble applying this filter to my existing code.

```
myInbox.Items.Restricted("DateValue[ReceivedTime] > "" & Format(DateValue(Now, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "")
```

Can someone with provide some pointers? Thanks in advance!

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Items
Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
Dim myitem As Object
Dim Found As Boolean

Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.Session.Folders.Item("test@test.com").Folders("My Folder").Items
' Need to apply filter to only pull items new than a specified date'
Found = False
       For Each myitem In myInbox
                 'This next line is checking all items in folder which is taking too long'
        If myitem.Class = olMail And myitem.ReceivedTime > Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value Then
               'Do something'
                Found = True
        End If
 Next myitem
 Set myOlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Apply the [`.Restrict(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-restrict-method-outlook) on the folder before going through the items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the obsession with `DateValue`?

---

This is wrong `Format(DateValue(Now, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")` and so is this `"DateValue[ReceivedTime]`

---

Even if you correct that syantax, you are trying to set a filter that is greater than current time, so you are trying to restrict your items for which are yet to be received:)

---

Use a variable to store a certain time (that is earlier to current date time)

Following code filters all the items received after 11/4/2017 10:25:00 PM

```
Sub test()

    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myitem As Object
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim TimeCrit    As Date

    TimeCrit = #11/4/2017 10:25:00 PM#

    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    ' Need to apply filter to only pull items new than a specified date'
    Set myItems = myInbox.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= """ & Format(TimeCrit, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """")

    Found = False
    For Each myitem In myItems
        MsgBox myitem.Subject
    Next myitem
    Set myOlApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you cyboashu! The filter applied to myItems worked perfectly!